# Use Raspberry pi 4 as router with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, dhcp

I was exploring creating my own router using Raspberry pi 4B (2GB model) and Ubuntu 20.04. I have seen few tutorials on how to create hotspot using hostapd and route traffic through all interfaces. I have `eth0` as WAN , `eth1` and `eth2` as LAN ports, `wlan0` and `wlan1` as wifi APs.

## Expected Setup

```
Internet <- eth0(WAN) -> Router (Raspberry PI 4B) <- eth1 eth2 wlan0 wlan1 (all on network 192.168.0.x) -> Local Machines

eth1 is connected to old router setup in bridge mode and has a private server connected to it.

In this setup i am expecting 3 wifi APs 2 from wlan0 and wlan1 on raspberry pi and one from old router connected in bridge mode on eth1.
```

## DHCP

**Installed isc-dhcp-server**

`sudo apt install isc-dhcp-server`

**Config**

`sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
...
# option definitions commonto all supported networks...
option domain-name "rpi.locl";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
#log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
range 192.168.0.50 192.168.0.215;
option routers 192.168.0.1;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
...
```

`sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

```
...
INTERFACESv4="eth1 eth2 wlan0 wlan1"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

## HOSTAPD config

External Wifi Adapter: [BrosTrend 1200Mbps Linux USB WiFi Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FCN6WGX)

```
ssid=your_ssid
wpa_passphrase=your_password

country_code=US

interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211

wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

macaddr_acl=0

logger_syslog=0
logger_syslog_level=4
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=0

hw_mode=a
wmm_enabled=1

# N
ieee80211n=1
require_ht=1
ht_capab=[MAX-AMSDU-3839][HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][DSSS_CCK-40]

# AC
ieee80211ac=1
require_vht=1
ieee80211d=0
ieee80211h=0
vht_capab=[MAX-AMSDU-3839][SHORT-GI-80]
vht_oper_chwidth=1
channel=36
#acs_num_scans=50
#acs_chan_bias=36:0.9 157:0.8 149:0.8
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
#supported_rates=8670
#beacon_rate=8670
```

```
iwconfig
wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"your_ssid"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Master  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=1/100  Signal level=-99 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

```
user@ubuntu:~$ iw list
Wiphy phy1
    max # scan SSIDs: 9
    max scan IEs length: 2304 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1963
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps
            * 5.5 Mbps
            * 11.0 Mbps
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x1863
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x03d071b2):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            SU Beamformee
            MU Beamformee
            +HTC-VHT
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 867 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 867 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (30.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (30.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (30.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (24.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm)
            * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
            * 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * set_bss
         * join_ibss
         * set_pmksa
         * del_pmksa
         * flush_pmksa
         * remain_on_channel
         * frame
         * set_channel
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xb0 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on anything (device continues operating normally)
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * monitor
    interface combinations are not supported
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports scan flush.
    Supported extended features:
```

## Iptables and Routing

I have created a `/etc/rc.local` file for iptables configs

```
#!/bin/bash

# /etc/rc.local

# Default policy to drop all incoming packets.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Accept incoming packets from localhost and the LAN interface.
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan1 -j ACCEPT


# Accept incoming packets from the WAN if the router initiated the connection.
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Forward LAN packets to the WAN.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

# Forward WAN packets to the LAN if the LAN initiated the connection.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan1 -m conntrack \
--ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# NAT traffic going out the WAN interface.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# rc.local needs to exit with 0
exit 0
```

## Challenges

There are few things I haven't solved yet in this section like:

1. Port forwarding- I want few ports opened on router and forward them to a machine `192.168.0.56` connected via eth1,
2. but I am unable to ping this machine from wlan0, wlan1, and eth2, so all machines connected via wlan0 or wlan1 or eth1 or eth2 can't talk to each other yet.
3. i was able to put external wifi card on VHT mode but still getting 300 Mbps link, `iw list` command says that 867 Mbps is supported, is there a special config of hostapd i have to enable ?

This is new for me so most probably i am doing a ton of things wrong. Any suggestions , how can i make this setup work ?

Comment: You have to enable IP forwarding (`sysct -wl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`)

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to mention that part, yes I have already done that.

Comment: apparently i was able to solve port forwarding partially, but it doesn't work from LAN